# The correct mental model for diamond inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to understand how the sizes of derived objects are constructed, especially in the case of diamond inheritance, and how virtual inheritance works.

Example of a diamond inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public A {
};

class D : public B, public C {
};
```

I say that the object of D will be of size 8 and this how i would visualize it:

[image]

The other example using virtual inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A {
};

class C : public virtual A {
};

class D : public B, public C {
};
```

I say that the object of D will be of size 24 and this how i would visualize it:

[image]

Could someone correct me if there is something I have misunderstood?"

Comment: Your first example is correct. It's been my experienced that most scholarly prose on this topic uses a flow diagram-type representation that portrays what the second example shows, which is incorrect and results in endless confusion.

Comment: Other than the bit about vptrs, your ven diagrams are largely correct. An implementation is not required to use vtables [even if it is a commonly used approach] and your classes have no virtual functions (so, even with implementations that use vtables, your classes won't have one).    However, that sort of Venn diagram isn't the only consideration affecting the size of an object - the compiler is free to introduce padding (essentially "space" between parts of an object) and often does in practice for various reasons.

Comment: pretty sure the three circles `A` and `B` and `C` in your second venn diagram shouldn't touch, and should be three separate circles.

Comment: @AhmedAEK   If we view the Venn diagram as identifying sets and subsets of the bits/bytes that represent an object, the virtual `A` may be considered part of the `B` and part of the `C`  (and part of `D`, since `B` and `C` are both parts of `D`)    So the intersection of `B` and `C` in a Venn diagram would amount to `A`.

Comment: The correct mental model is to avoid diamond inheritance alltogether, it is usually a desing flaw (and an indication inheritance is only used for code reuse). Use abstract baseclasses and (CRTP) mixin classes for your code reuse.

Comment: @Peter the `B` contained in there is not a complete object, it cannot act as the original `B`, it is not equivalent to it, `B` needs figures out that it is originally an object of type `D` to be able to use `A`, this deduction happens at runtime, using the `vtable` of `D`, since `B` doesn't own `A`, therefore `A` is not a subset of `B`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK -- every `B` object has a corresponding `A` subobject. That `A` object can be in different places, depending on whether there's a derived type involved, but it's always there, and the `B` object always knows how to find it. Yes, the location of the `A` subobject has to be determined at runtime, but that doesn't make the `B` object incomplete in any way.

Comment: @PeteBecker the fact that the `B` cannot act on its own without involving `D` is enough to separate them, conceptually `B` has to go through `D` to reach `A`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK -- that's just not true. Every `B` object knows how to reach its `A` subobject. The relevant data is set up when the `B` object is constructed. The runtime lookup doesn't involve the `D` part at all. Don't forget, you can create objects of type `B` and use their `A` subobject; there is no role for the derived class when the `A` subobject is accessed.

Comment: @PeteBecker does the compiler generate one `vtable` for the `B` that's part of `D` and another one for the `B` that is not a part of `D` ?

Comment: Nice diagrams; they precisely capture what's going on.

Comment: @AhmedAEK -- would you assert that a base class that has virtual functions is incomplete because the derived class sets up the vtable? Same thing here: the data that the `B` object needs to access its `A` subobject is setup in in the constructor. Any runtime lookup is done purely from the `B` subobject; its vtable has all the information that's needed. A standalone `B` object has a vtable that's appropriate for it, set in the constructor; a `B` object that's a subobject of some other type has a vtable that's appropriate for it, set in the constructor.

Comment: @AhmedAEK -- so, yes, there are multiple vtables, but only one is registered in the `B` object, the one that's appropriate to the role of the `B` object in the inheritance hierarchy. `B` doesn't know or care where its vtable pointer came from; it just uses it.